# Show that f and e^f can not have a common pole

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorpic on a punctured neighborhood of $z_o$. Show that $f$ and $e^f$ can not have a common pole.

My attempt at solution is WLOG let $z_o =0$ be a pole of $f$. Then the Laurent series of $f$ is
$$
f(z)= a_{-n} z^{-n} + \cdots + a_0 + a_1 z+ \cdots
$$

and so 
\begin{align}
e^f &= \exp(f) = \exp(a_{-n} z^{-n} + \cdots + a_0 + \cdots) \\
&= \exp(a_{-n} z^{-n}) \exp(a_{-n + 1} z^{-n} + 1 + \cdots + a_0 + a_1 z + \cdots) \\
& = (1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots)\bigg|_{a_{-n} z^{-n}} \cdot \exp(\cdots) \\
&= (1+ a_{-n} z^{-n} + \frac{a_n z^{-2n}}{2!} + \cdots ) \exp(a_{n+1} z^{-n+1} + \cdots)
\end{align}
and then show that the Laurent series has infinitely many negative order terms, hence has an essential singularity at 0, and not a pole.

I dont know if this is the right approach, could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $f$ has pole at $z=z_0$. Then $g = 1/f$ has a removable singularity at $z=z_0$ and we can put $g(z_0) = 0$ to get a holomorphic function near $z_0$. By the open mapping theorem ($g$ can't be constant), the image under $g$ of a small disc centered at $z_0$ contains another small disc centered at $0$.

Hence $f$ maps every  small punctured disc centered at $z_0$ onto a set containing $|w| > R$ for some $R > 0$ (depending on the radius of the small disc). This means that it can't be the case that
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0} |\exp(f(z))| = \infty
$$
(the image contains points where $\exp(f(z)) \approx 0$). So $\exp f$ can't have a pole at $z=z_0$.

Comment: Thanks, why would f having pole at zo => 1/f has a removable singularity at zo? and why would g(z)->0 as z->zo?

Comment: A function $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ if and only if $\lim_{z\to z_0} |f(z)| = \infty$.

Comment: Ohh true. Ok also my next question, by what I know of the open mapping theorem, it basically says that f sends open sets to open sets. But how do you get that the image under g of disk centered at zo contains another small disk centered at zo?

Comment: typo fixed - the image contains a small disc centered at $0$, not $x_0$